# pushing a DetailViewController from a table in another DetailViewController programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I used `ShowDetailSegue` to push a `DetailVewController` from another `DetailViewController`. there is no issues. But my need is to push to a `DetailedViewController` from a `TableView` in another `DetailedViewController`.
I used the below code for pushing:-

```
PushUpExerciseViewController *pushUpObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushUpID"];
        [self presentViewController:pushUpObj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After using this code in my TableView `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` the `MasterViewController` is missing. i need both Master and Detailed `ViewControllers`. How to push from TableView in `DetailViewController` to another `DetailViewController` Programatically

Comment: Simply push the new viewcontroller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply push to View Controller.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailVewController *objDetailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVewController"];
    //Pass the data here to DetailViewController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDetailVC animated:YES];
}
```

As you told you need to push `DetailedViewController` from another `DetailedViewController` instance on TableViewCell selection. In this case you need prevent the infinite loop of push.

**Flow**

`Master (Push) -> Detail (Push on didSelectRowAtIndexPath ) -> Detail`

Comment: @MahinIbrahim what problem you are facing now ?

Comment: NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], videoObj, nil];
    
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

Comment: VideoPlayViewController *videoObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoPlayID"];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], videoObj, nil];
 self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

Comment: Your solution and question is mismatch bro.